# In Galois theory, why solvable groups must have their quotient groups be Abelian?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, galois-theory

The definition of solvable groups can be regarded as two constraints, one is that there must be a sequence of normal subgroups, and the other is that the quotient groups between these sequences are Abelian groups. The first one is well understood, but I don't quite understand the second constraint. To be specific, why must the commutative law hold? I know that the root formula of the quintic equation can be expressed in the Bring radicals, but A5 does not satisfy the commutative law (non-Abelian group). So what is the special property that binds the algebraic radicals and commutative law of quotient groups? And what makes algebraic radicals different from Bring radicals?

Comment: What do you mean by “the first one is well understood”? Did you try to read a proof in a Galois theory book that solvable equations (in characteristic 0) have solvable Galois groups? Or do you know why the splitting field of $x^n-a$ (in characteristic 0) has a solvable Galois group?

Comment: *"one is that there must be a sequence of normal subgroups"*: no , this is not a constraint. Every group has a normal series. And your second "constraint" *"the quotient groups between these sequences are Abelian groups"* is senseless by itself, since it makes reference to the normal series of the "first constraint". So you should view the whole definition as a single constraint.

Comment: Maybe OP would be satisfied with an explanation of "what makes algebraic radicals different from Bring radicals," but I agree that this website is not the appropriate place for such an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A solvable group is, by definition, a group with a finite series of normal subgroups such that the successive factor groups are abelian. It is the content of the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory that a finite Galois extension $L\supset K$ of fields has solvable Galois group (the group of field automorphisms of $L$ that pointwise fix $K$) if and only if the elements of $L$ can be expressed in terms of the elements of $K$ using only the extraction of $n$th roots for each $n$ together with the standard field operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

Regarding your comment about $A_5$, note that not only is $A_5$ non-abelian but it is not solvable. By contrast, the alternating group $A_4$, which is also non-abelian, *is* solvable.